# C++ Read/write file on Unix

Tags: c++

I know this is a very specific question. I am compiling a c++ code using g++ compiler on a unix machine.
I have the following one line code to read a text file specified as parameter in C++: test.cc

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    ifstream inputfile(argv[1]);

}
```

Now after compiling with g++, I will call it as:

```
./test file.txt
```

But what should I do, if I want to call it as

```
./test <file.txt
```

In short how do I do a file read using default input/output

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7789007/14065

Comment: do you mean you want to read from `stdin` as well, or instead of `inputfile`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check the arguments to `main` to see if there is an argument given to the program. If it is then you can use that as the file, otherwise you use `std::cin`.

Here is an example:

```
void do_something(istream &input)
{
    // Read some stuff from the input
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1)
        do_something(cin);
    else if (argc == 2)
        do_something(ifstream(argv[1]));
    else
    {
        cout << "Error: Must supply a file\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The reason I call another function to read and process the input, is because you can not assign streams, but must use references or pointers. It's also good to put separate tasks in separate functions, because it will increase readability of the code.

Comment: Joachim, just a query, so using the above code, if I run the compiled program as ./test <file.txt will it pass the contents of the file to do_something istream?

Comment: @user1035927 Yes it should. Go ahead, try it. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to read from standard input, use `std::cin` instead of opening your own stream.

For example:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using < redirects that file to stdin, so you'd get at it via std::cin in c++.

Answer (score 0):

You need instead to read from stdin, da file.

in other words read from the keyboard.

when you pipe stuff in, it will be read as if typed from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what most of the Unix commands do: read from the file if the filename is specified. If the file name is missing read from standard input.

Answer (score 0):

The `cin` object is already defined in `iostream`. Just read from `cin` instead of `inputfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
ifstream &myin;
if (argc>1) {
   ifstream* inputfilep = new infstream(argv[1]);
   myin = *inputfile;
}
else myin = cin;
/* do your input on myin */
```

Comment: References must be initialized at construction.  Make it a pointer instead, or do it with the conditional `ifstream &myin = (argc>1?*new infstream(argv[1]):cin);`  (don't forget to delete myin if argc>1!)

Answer (score 0):

you will need to modify your example to check argc to see if any command line arguments are passed in, as the input redirection is stripped off by the shell so if argc is 0 then read from standard in as given by the other examples, otherwise as your example code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything.
Just write your program as if your are reading from the command line.